# Angular Http Delete request returning undefined [MEAN stack]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I'm trying to delete the refresh token from the server when the user clicks logout.

auth.service.ts

```
deleteToken(refreshToken:any){
    return this.http.delete(`${environment.baseUrl}/logout`, refreshToken).toPromise()
  }
```

header.component.ts

```
refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken')
logout = async()=>{
    try {
      console.log(this.refreshToken)
      await this.authService.deleteToken({refreshToken:this.refreshToken})
      localStorage.removeItem("refreshToken");
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

The console.log(this.refreshToken) is the token from local storage so that works.

Backend authController.js

```
exports.deleteToken = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let user = await User.findOne({ refreshToken: req.body.refreshToken })
        console.log(req.body.refreshToken)
        if (req.body.refreshToken == user.refreshToken) {
            await user.updateOne({ $unset: { refreshToken: "" } });
            res.sendStatus(200);
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({ message: "Error while deleting token" })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

When i console.log(req.body.refreshToken) it is undefined

Comment: Try `req.body` instead

Comment: @GuerricP if you meant in the backend, doesn't work, returned an empty object

Answer (score 0):

If this solution is right, the delete request doesn't have a body in it. So the request should be like this:

```
deleteToken(refreshToken:any){
    return this.http.request('DELETE', `${environment.baseUrl}/logout`, {
      body: { refreshToken: refreshToken }
  }).toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: FYI the Restful approach to this problem is to pass an identifier of the user in the URL (i.e: `/logout/user_id`) then the backend would retrieve the token from a header (often `Authorization` or `Cookie`) and invalidate it.